# SWT.Browser drop target

Tags: java, swt

I want to implement a drag drop operation using Eclipse RAP framework. I am able to do it with two tables, one is drag source and the other is drop source but what I want is, I want to take  item names from a table drag them to a SWT Browser object and see them in that browser.

For example I drag a label to Browser and drop it, then i see that label on my browser.

I searched it but i couldn't find a solution. Any suggestion to achive this would be very helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This may be difficult due to this bug:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=397557

What you could try is (using the Browser widget as a drop target) to disable the browser on drag start and enable it after the drop.